# apache poi read XSSFWorkbook, nothing happen

Tags: java, apache-poi

i have a strange problem..
i can't open xslm file with apache poi.. file is 12mb, not corrupted
if open with excel is all ok
if open in internal editor eclipse works (2 minutes for open but work)
but if i try open with java and apache poi nothing happen... no errors, no timeout.. nothing..
passed over 10minutes...
with task manager i see java memory growing...
but never finish.. my code is here..

```
public XSSFWorkbook openExcelFile(String excelFilePath) throws IOException {
XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFilePath);
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    //workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(new File(excelFilePath));
    //Workbook workbook_test = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(excelFilePath));
    //Workbook workbook_test = StreamingReader.builder().rowCacheSize(100) 
    //.bufferSize(4096) 
    //.open(new File(excelFilePath)); 
}finally{
    inputStream.close();
}
return workbook;
```

}

Comment: Workbooks that include macros are still problematic and not fully supported in Apache POI. Consult the documentation in order to find out about details concerning support of .xlsm files.

Comment: but macros are empty, have only formulas !

Comment: Does it work when you store that workbook as `.xlsx` instead of `.xlsm`?

Comment: no, but now give me an error is good this, is a trace.. ! java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: How much heap size did you give your JVM ?

Comment: default, now i tryed -Xmx8192m and work.. slow but works... used 4gb from heap...